# Source in Arabic for "ושמע האמת ממי שאמרה"

Tags: sources-mekorot, rambam, pirke-avot-ethicsof, arabic

Rambam says "ושמע האמת ממי שאמרה" ("Accept the truth from whomever says it") in [Shmonah Perakim](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/mahshevt/shmona/hakdamat-2.htm). Does anyone know what he said in the original Judeo Arabic?

Comment: I've always heard it as "kabel haemes mimi she'amra" (same idea, slightly different wording); would have to check something like R' Kafeh's translation.

Answer (score 17):

It is ואסמע אלחק ממן קאלה.

You can read the Judeo-Arabic original (in Hebrew letters, as it was written) [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=CLcFAAAAYAAJ&pg).

——

> Arabic lettering for reference:
>
> واسمع الحق ممن قاله
>
> wasmae alhaqa mmn qalaha

Comment: This is on the second line from the bottom in p.6 of the Hebrew/Judeo-Arabic section in the back of the book, which is p.155 in the Google book reader. But it seems that the second word actually is אלחק with a "chet" to correspond to the Arabic حق.

Comment: s did a post about it here

http://onthemainline.blogspot.com/2011/01/on-intellectual-honesty.html#comments